# Как реализовать связь ManyToMany экземпляров одной модели между собой?

Tags: python, django

Вот такая простая модель для станций метро. Название и та же самая станция на другой ветке.

```py
class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    duplicate = models.ManyToManyField('Station', null=True, blank=True)
```

Использую родную админку Django.

Допустим, есть 2 станции - Достоевская и Владимирская. Мне нужно их друг к другу привязать. Захожу в Достоевскую, привязываю к ней Владимирскую. Но если захожу теперь во Владимирскую, Достоевская к ней не привязана.

Как сделать, чтобы при связке эти станции друг к другу добавлялись? А при удалении - удалялись. Пробовал через сигнал m2m_changed, но что-то пока тоже ерунда получается. Надо копать в его сторону, или есть что-то из коробки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогла замена названия класса в связи на self:

```
class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    duplicate = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

Comment: Возможно, Вам ещё понадобится аргумент `symmetrical` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 Да, спасибо, кажется это то, что нужно